# why onkeypress doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the html control code I have just ran in fiddler:

```
<input type="text" id="txtname" value="John" onkeypress="return false;"/>
```

- **Case 1** (Chrome) : The above code let me delete text in textbox but not letting to insert new text into the same.
- **Case 2** (Firefox) : Don't letting neither delete nor insert.

Why this is so? How to solve this?

> Finally why this result are different than each other?

Comment: Because you return false. What do you wanna do ?

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? What are you trying to do?

Comment: What I want is not to let anything with textbox value neither insertion not deletion, but in chrome I able to delete that text within textbox..

Comment: what about right-click, select all, right-click, cut.  No keypresses involved.  You want a `readonly` textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I want is not to let anything with textbox value neither insertion not deletion

I think you're looking for `readonly` (no js code needed):

```html
<input type="text" id="txtname" value="John" readonly/>
```

---

> But what if I want to let user only to delete and not to let him insert text into

In this case you can allow just `backspace` (code 8) and `delete` (code 46) :

```html
<input type="text" id="txtname" value="John" 
onkeydown='return event.which == 46 ||  event.which == 8' required />
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ohh this is one case where we don't let user to do anything with textbox values. But what if I want to let user only to delete and not to let him insert text into, as it happening in chrome??

Comment: @Kaishu what if they make a typo and need to delete a character?  If you want to display something without letting them edit it, put it in a span outside the textbox or similar.

Comment: @James, actually values for textbox getting set from popup list on button click even near to textbox..

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki, but as mentioned  above `<input type="text" id="txtname" value="John" onkeypress="return false;"/>` should not let to do anything so why chrome not restricting for textbox??

Comment: I'm not sure why @Kaishu but using `onkeydown` will solve the issue in this case.

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki, I test that with`onkeydown` that is working but in my case textbox actually defined as:

Comment: `<input name="tcProperty$tab0$CoListAgentID" type="text" value="Abernathy , Scott" id="tcProperty_tab0_CoListAgentID" tabindex="-1" class="ListText" onkeydown="return (event.keyCode!=13);" initclass="ListText" datatype="CHARACTER" onkeypress="return false;" style="width:135px;" title="Abernathy , Scott" spellcheck="true">`